# "engaged" mean in this context

Tags: word-meaning

> The gunman was **engaged** by responding officers within about 1 minute and taken into custody, officials from Anne Arundel County Government said.

According to [the Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/engage), **engage** can mean:

> 3. verb
>      If you engage someone in conversation, you have a conversation with them.

Or

> 7. verb
>      When a military force engages the enemy, it attacks them and starts a battle.

So, what's **engage** supposed to mean in this context?

[The full source](https://www.yahoo.com/gma/active-shooter-reported-newspaper-annapolis-police-194503709--abc-news-topstories.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a very basic level, it simply means they

> **interacted**

in some way, either by shooting or possibly by conversation and negotiation.  If you are

> **engaged in conversation**

you are *interacting* with someone and *talking* to them.

Comment: So, what is it in this context? Is it attacking/shooting or just having a conversation with the gunman? That's the part that confused me originally.

Comment: From the context, all we know is the police captured the gunman. We do not know how. Considering guns were involved, it was probably by force.

Comment: is it possible that the official was trying to deliberately hide in  what way they captured the gunman, and so they used the word 'engage'?

Comment: It is a possible motivation, but it is also fairly standard *police-speak*.